# How to send a callback from a javascript class js

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm trying to send a callback from a javascript class to its object. I haven't gotten anywhere with it.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(param1, param2) {
      // trigger the callback
      this.callback();
   }
}

obj = MyClass({
    parameter1: 'test',
    parameter2: 'test',
    callback() {
        alert('callback received');
    }
});
```

Comment: that's not how you create instances of classes in javascript

Comment: What does that mean, *"send a callback from a javascript class to its object"*? Unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JaromandaX typo, my bad. Just fixed

Comment: you're calling `new MyClass` with an argument, but have no parameters on `constructor` ... the arguments passed in `new MyClass` will be parameters on the `constructor`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I might be wording / explaining it wrong, but essentially I'm trying to acheive something similar to an ajax success callback, where 'test = new MyClass' would be the ajax request.

Comment: this looks like there's some fundamental lack of knowledge around how classes work in JS. MDN is always a reasonably decent starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes see the calcArea and accessors examples there.

Comment: @Mike perhaps if you showed how you really want to use such a construct, someone may be able to guide you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pass a callback function as an argument to the constructor:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(callback) {
    callback();
  }
}

new MyClass(() => console.log('Called back'));
```